# Is there any documentation other than the official documentation?

Tags: sproutcore

The official documentation seems to be light on explanations of 'how to understand the SproutCore way' e. g., why things are done the way they are, how to intuit what to do from where you're at, etc.

Comment: Don't forget that you can always ask question here on Stack Overflow. There are a couple of Sproutcore developers here.

Comment: Also there's something called "SproutHub" which will be appearing in a few months time for an invitation only beta. It's acknowledged that the situation sucks at present according to the people in the sproutcore IRC channel on Freenode.

Answer (score 2):

[Update] Latest resource is [new wiki](http://wiki.sproutcore.com/) .

Which have information on how to start with Version 1.0 Alpha

Answer (score 0):

There is a GitHub Wiki on sproutcore.  They give a good list of howtos and tutorials.
http://github.com/sproutit/sproutcore/wikis

It is supposed to be a fairly easy javascript framework to learn, but it has its moments.